# Is it possible to define an automorphism on the structure $\mathfrak{Q}=(\mathbb{Q},<)$ and what would be an example?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, first-order-logic

In this case < is interpreted as the normal comparison operator on $\mathbb{Q}$. My current thoughts say no, since there is no possibility to define a function with just the < operator and we are quite limited by the signature. My overall goal is to prove that there is no function $\phi(\mathfrak{Q}) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and I think that an automorphism is the way to go. But somehow I cannot come up with an automorphism on $\mathbb{Q}$ with the given signature.

Comment: $x\mapsto x+1$?

Comment: That boils down to one of my other questions: Are we able to use other symbols in our bijection for the automorphism or are we limited to the relation symbols of our given signature?

Comment: Well, that's for _you_ to decide.  What is your definition of "create"?

Comment: What do you mean by "create an automorphism"? If you are asking about ***definability*** why don't you just say so in your question?

Comment: Good point, I'll refine my question

Comment: The question is whether there is an automorphism of $\mathfrak Q$ (yes), and whether *you* can define it (yes), not whether there is a formula (with two free variables and parameters) in the language of $\mathfrak Q$ whose interpretation in $\mathfrak Q$ happens to be the graph of an automorphism.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Shouldn't an automorphism consist of an bijection from $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$(in this case), not a logical formula? But in essence that is my question, probably my lack of mathematical rigour causes the confusion in the group of commentators

Comment: The confusion seems to be in your part. You understood the question as requiring that the automorphism $f$ be definable in the language of the structure. This means precisely that there is a formula $\phi(x,y,z_1,\dots,z_n)$ such that for some $c_1,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb Q$, $\{(a,b)\in \mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q\mid \mathfrak Q\models\phi(a,b,\vec c)\}$ is the graph $\{(a,f(a))\mid a\in\mathbb Q\}$ of $f$.

Comment: Ok, it seems like I am not sure what I want to ask. Thank you all or your input. Since the question is obviously flawed by nature, I am going to delete it.

Comment: If you are asking whether there is a *nontrivial* automorphism definable in the first order language with only $<$ in signature, without parameters, then the answer is no, though it will take a bit work to show.